# Laravel delete original image and retina version

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make retina ready design, so when I upload image it's uploading one with original name and low quality and one with high quality added @2x to end of name. My question is how to delete both of them as I have only original name with extension? Here is what I tried:

```
$destination_path   = public_path() . 'storage/cover_photos/';

$old_cover = $destination_path . $this->cover_name;
$old_cover_retina = $destination_path . $old_cover->getClientOriginalName() . '@2x' . $this->old_cover->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

$this->cover_name returns the name of image in string like "name.jpg".

I'm getting this error:

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object
```

Am I need to convert $old_cover to an object or there is a another way?

Comment: You're setting `$old_cover` to be a string, but then you're attempting to use it as an object.

Comment: yes I know, but how can I get original name and add @2x to end of this before extension?

Comment: Do you have an object with the original name as a property? Or do you store the original name anywhere? Perhaps if you update the question with some more detail, examples of the file names you have, and what information you currently store then it'll be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get details about a particular file, including the filename and the extension. So then you should be able to do something like this:

```
$fileinfo = pathinfo($destination_path . $this->cover_name);
$old_cover_retina = $destination_path . $fileinfo['filename'] . '@2x' . $fileinfo['extension'];
```